# Geometry to world origin on load

Tags: objects, transforms, origin

I'm having a strange issue where my original project is ok, with all its objects in their correct places, with their origins set to the base of each of them, without parentings just collections and no strange keyframes set. This file loads ok on my machine (Win11, Blender 2.93.18):
[image]

Then, I bring this file to a different computer (Ubuntu 18.04, Blender 2.93.18) and when loaded I see all objects centered to world origin, but with its origins displaced as if only geometry was moved:
[image]

I have no clue what's going on. What can I do to prevent that displacement?

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, to check on a third system ?

Comment: Just added a simplified version of the scene.

Comment: On my system (MacOS 10.15.7 and Blender 3.6.5), the top view from your file looks like the first picture of your post (with Win11), with buildings spread over the "ground" plane (but I do not see the street map as background...).

Comment: I think I missed to integrate the street map. Anyway it looks like you're able to load it as it should be.